# jar not compatible with project in scala OpenIE?

Tags: java, jar

when I add these jar on project. project is not compiling and giving an red Error on project.

clear-parse-models-1.3.0.jar

clear-postag-models-1.3.0.jar

clear-pred-models-1.3.0.jar

clear-role-models-1.3.0.jar

Comment: Welcome SO.Where you add this jar files ?? either build-classpath or folder of in you project??

Comment: @Ami in the buildpath

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @migueljimenezz i am using eclipseIDE so i am not getting run as. and project showing 'red !' and not compiling. i trying to run OpenIE scala project.

Comment: Please show us a little bit more. Is it possible to upload an screen shot? or maybe a copy-paste of the error.

Comment: i dont have much reputation to add snap?

Comment: error when i am running as java application
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/knowitall/openie/openIECli

it is a scala project?